# Ramda: How to change only one value of an object, based the object's other values

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm building a React app. I'm using Ramda to help me with functional programming.

If you want to see the full code, I also asked for help on [StackExchange Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/219085/transform-vcards-into-contacts-using-functional-programming-in-javascript).

For Stack Overflow only one part is relevant, though.

How can you change a specific value from an object based on the object's other values using Ramda? I use `mapObjIndexed` which in the process maps over all keys.

**Context:** I have on object representing a contact with several keys which are all strings. The object always has a key called `contactDetails`. I want to calculate the value of `contactDetails` dependant of the values of the object's `tel`, `bday` and `email` keys.

If a contact looks like this before the function:

```
{
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  contactDetails: '',
  tel: '555-55-5555',
  bday: '',
  email: 'john@doe.com'
}
```

it should look like this afterwards:

```
{
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  contactDetails: 'john@doe.com 555-55-5555',
  tel: '555-55-5555',
  bday: '',
  email: 'john@doe.com'
}
```

The function that I wrote for this looks like this:

```
R.mapObjIndexed((val, key, obj) =>
  key === 'contactDetails'
    ? R.trim(
        R.replace(
          /undefined/g,
          '',
          `${R.prop('bday')(obj)} ${R.prop('tel')(obj)} ${R.prop('email')(
            obj
          )}`
        )
      )
    : val
),
```

As you can see this is a pretty unclean and hacky way abusing `map`. Is there a better way to change an object's value in Ramda based on other values of the object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless this is an exercise in learning Ramda, I would suggest that a simpler technique than anything you're likely to come up with from Ramda is the straightforward object destructuring approach:

```js
const transform = ({tel, bday, email, ...rest}) => ({
  ...rest, tel, bday, email,
  contactDetails: [bday, email, tel].join(' ').trim()
})

const obj = {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', tel: '555-55-5555', bday: '', email: 'john@doe.com'}

console.log(transform(obj))
```

This version does not depend upon the key `contactDetails` being already present, although it won't hurt if it is there.

If you're really worried about a possible double-space between words (for example, if `bday` and `tel` are supplied, but `email` is empty), you can modify it to this:

```js
const combine = (ss) => ss.reduce((a, s) => a + (s.length ? ' ' : '') + s, '').trim()

const transform = ({tel, bday, email, ...rest}) => ({
  ...rest, tel, bday, email,
  contactDetails: combine([bday, email, tel])
})
```

I'm one of the founders of Ramda and a big fan, but it is only a toolkit.  There are plenty of places where it helps make your code easier to read and to write; by all means use it then.  But when it doesn't do so, even in a code-base heavily using Ramda, then skip it and use other techniques.

Comment: Thank you as always Scott. I love how you answer almost every question tagged with Ramda. It really helps people learn 

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to Ori's answer, we can update the property using `R.assoc('contactDetails')`, building a list of the desired property values using `R.juxt` and `R.propOr('')` to default any missing properties, rejecting any empty strings before joining them together with `R.join`.

```js
// takes a list of property names, returning a function that accepts an object
// and produces a list of the values of the provided properties, defaulting to
// an empty string if null or undefined.
const defProps =
  R.compose(R.juxt, R.map(R.propOr('')))

const fn =
  // When `g` is a function, `R.chain(f, g)(x)` is equivalent to `f(g(x), x)`
  R.chain(
    R.assoc('contactDetails'),
    R.pipe(
      defProps(['bday', 'tel', 'email']),
      R.reject(R.equals('')),
      R.join(' ')))

console.log(fn({
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  contactDetails: '',
  tel: '555-55-5555',
  bday: '',
  email: 'john@doe.com'
}))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use R.converge to merge the original object, and the result of R.pipe that generates the `contactDetails` property. The pipe gets an array of values via R.props, filters out falsy values (undefined, empty strings, nulls, etc...), joins the the items with spaces, and wrap the value with an object with R.objOf.

```js
const { converge, merge, identity, pipe, props, filter, join, trim, objOf } = R

const fn = converge(merge, [identity, pipe(
  props(['bday', 'tel', 'email']),
  filter(Boolean),
  join(' '),
  objOf('contactDetails')
)])

const obj = {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  contactDetails: '',
  tel: '555-55-5555',
  bday: '',
  email: 'john@doe.com'
}

const result = fn(obj)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```